# Ideal structure of a tensor product of certain algebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, tensor-products, ideals

I would be grateful if anyone could give me a reference regarding the following question.

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two unital prime algebras over a field $F$ whose center consists of scalar multiples of identity (so called central algebras). Assume that both $A$ and $B$ have a unique non-trivial two-sided ideal, denote it respectively by $J_A$ and $J_B$. I'm interested about the ideal structure of a tensor product $A \otimes B$ (over $F$). The obvious non-trivial ideals of $A \otimes B$ are  $J_A \otimes J_B$, $A \otimes J_B$, $J_A \otimes B$ and $J_A\otimes B + A \otimes J_B$. Are there some conditions on $A$ and $B$ that guarantee these are the only non-trivial ideals of $A \otimes B$?

I'm particularly interested in a case when $A=B$ is the algebra of $F$-linear maps on some vector space over $F$ of infinite countable dimension. Then the only non-trivial ideal of $A$ is the ideal  $J_A$ of finite rank maps. Are all ideals of $A \otimes A$ of the above form?

Comment: too old but related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/86217/85967

Answer (score 3):

Well, i do not know the answer in general but since you are asking for a reference and if

> there are some conditions on $A$ and $B$ that guarantee these are the only non-trivial ideals of $A \otimes B$?

There are some related results, for example:
Let $B$ an arbitrary algebra over a field.

> Every ideal of the algebra $A\otimes B$, where $A$ is a central simple algebra, is of the form $A\otimes I$, where $I$ is an ideal of the algebra $B$.

This is theorem 4.3.2, p. 74, from the [book of Drozd-Kirichenko](https://www.imath.kiev.ua/~drozd/drozd-kirichenko_en.pdf).
 (although i suspect this may not be of much use for the particular case you are interested in, as explained in the last paragraph of the OP).

Maybe [this reference](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82260697.pdf) might also be of some interest to you.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of all this. I'm interested if something can be said abut the ideal structure $A \otimes B$ when both central algebras $A$ and $B$ have a unique non-trivial two-sided ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is true for your example.

By a similar proof as mentioned by Konstantinos Kanakoglou, we have the following fact.

- Let $I$ be an ideal of $A \otimes B$. If $I \nsubseteq J_A \otimes J_B$, then $I = J_A \otimes B, A \otimes J_B$ or $J_A \otimes B + A \otimes J_B$.

Now suppose that $A=B$ is the algebra of $F$-linear maps on some vector space over $F$ of infinite countable dimension. For all $0 \neq \sum x_i\otimes y_i \in J_A\otimes J_A$, $x_i,y_i(\in J_A)$ can be seen as endmorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space. Hence $\exists 0 \neq x,y \in J_A$, such that $x \otimes y \in $ the ideal generated by $\sum x_i\otimes y_i$. The ideal generated by $x \otimes y$ is just $J_A \otimes J_A$, then we have

- If $I$ is a subideal of $J_A \otimes J_A$, then $I = 0$ or $J_A \otimes J_A$.

So $A\otimes A$ has only four nonzero ideals.

Comment: In the mean time I proved this is indeed true for $\mathrm{End}_F(V) \otimes \mathrm{End}_F(V)$, where $V$ is a vect. space of infinite countable dimension over a filed $F$. But if $A$ and $B$ are as in my original post and $I$ an ideal of $A \otimes B$  such that $I$ is not contained in $J_A \otimes J_B$, why is $I$ is necessarily of the form $J_A \otimes B$, $A \otimes J_B$ or $J_A \otimes B+ A \otimes J_B$? BTW, if both $A$ and $B$ are centrally closed then $J_A \otimes J_B$ is indeed the smallest proper ideal of $A \otimes B$ by the main result of Nicholson-Watters' paper from 1983 (PAMS).

Comment: Thanks. Also like the proof of (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) in Nicholson-Watters' main result. If $I$ is not contained in $J_A \otimes J_B$, we can assume that $r_1 = 1$ or $s_1 = 1$. So $0 \neq 1 \otimes s_1 \in I$ or $0 \neq r_1 \otimes 1 \in I$. Hence $ J_A \otimes B \subset I$ or  $ A \otimes J_B \subset I$. So we can assume that $A$ or $B$ is a simple algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the solution to this problem is as simple as rpz says. In fact, I wrote a short paper about this so, in case if anyone is interested, please check Thm. 3.9 of https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~ilja/preprints/ISTPNSA.pdf